# namespace error in store procedure sql

Tags: sql, asp.net, xml

asp.net,vb.net. The objective is to copy XML data into a table (customerDetail), but when i execute the stored procedure, the XML data is not copied to the table and i do not get any errors.

**my xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<q:Customers xmlns="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/bed/1.2" xmlns:catalog="http://anss.org/xmlns/catalog/0.1" xmlns:q="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/quakeml/1.2">
  <Customer Id ="1">
    <Name>John Hammond</Name>
    <Country>United States</Country>
  </Customer>
  <Customer Id = "2">
    <Name>Mudassar Khan</Name>
    <Country>India</Country>
  </Customer>
    <Customer Id ="3">
    <Name>Suzanne Mathews</Name>
    <Country>France</Country>
  </Customer>
    <Customer Id ="4">
    <Name>Robert Schidner</Name>
    <Country>Russia</Country>
  </Customer>
</q:Customers>
```

**my stored procedure:**

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertXML]
@xml XML
AS
BEGIN

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://quakeml.org/xmlns/quakeml/1.2' as q)
  INSERT INTO CustomerDetails
  SELECT
  Customer.value('@Id','INT') AS CustomerId, --ATTRIBUTE
  Customer.value('(Name/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS Names, --TAG
  Customer.value('(Country/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS Country --TAG
  FROM
  @xml.nodes('//q:Customers/Customer') as TEMPTABLE(Customer)
  END
```

**my vb.net code behind in asp.net**

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class UploadXml
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub UploadXML(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As   System.EventArgs)        Handles btn_upload.Click
    Dim fileName As String =     Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
    Dim filePath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") & fileName
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath)
    Dim xml As String = File.ReadAllText(filePath)
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("InsertXML")
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xml", xml)
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
   End Sub
    End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customer belongs to the default namespace `http://quakeml.org/xmlns/bed/1.2`.

Try this:

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://quakeml.org/xmlns/quakeml/1.2' as q,
                    default 'http://quakeml.org/xmlns/bed/1.2')
SELECT
  Customer.value('@Id','INT') AS CustomerId, --ATTRIBUTE
  Customer.value('(Name/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS Names, --TAG
  Customer.value('(Country/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS Country --TAG
  FROM
  @xml.nodes('/q:Customers/Customer') as TEMPTABLE(Customer);
```

Comment: cool man :), it work awesome but do you think i can use this method to store the following xml in a database table. the xml is : http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.quakeml

Comment: could you check my new post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731422/asp-net-repeater-eval-not-reading-value-from-table-containong-200-records

Comment: @nadia Checked it but Javascript and asp is not for me so can't help you there.

Comment: check this post it on sql OpenXML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749172/openxml-sql-server-for-complex-xml-document-help-please-its-urgent