# Extract XML using OPENXML()

Tags: sql-server, xml, openxml, prefix

My problem is that I do not know how to extract the XML tag element using OpenXML. Any clarification would be great.

I have using xml.node before but now I am transitioning to OpenXML

My XML document can be [found here](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.quakeml)

**My Stored procedure:**

```
  ALTER procedure [dbo].[WEEKXml]
(@xmlstr ntext)

as

begin

  declare @hDoc int
  exec sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT,@xmlstr    



  insert into tbl_weekquake


    select xml.time,xml.longitude,xml.latitude,xml.depth,xml.mag,xml.type,xml.description,xml.text
    from OPENXML(@hDoc,'/q:quakeml/eventParameters/event',2)
    with([time] varchar(300) 'times',
         latitude numeric(18,6),
         longitude numeric(18,6) ,
         depth varchar(50),
         mag varchar(50)'magnitude',
        type varchar(50) 'mag_type',
        description     varchar(max) 'placer',
        [text] varchar(50)'type')xml
        exec sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc 

END
```

Comment: What does this have to do with ASP.NET?

Comment: @mason i used asp.net store procedure to insert in db

Comment: There is no such thing as "ASP.NET Stored Procedure". Stored procedures are a SQL Server concept, not a web platform concept. Accordingly, I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

One of your issues is that OPENXML does not handle "default namespace" very well.  (besides the fact that no one recommends its usage anymore).

Here is how to force the use of a default namespace with openxml.

(from http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10501/xquery-lab-59-openxml-and-xml-namespace-declarations.aspx )

```
declare @xmlDoc nvarchar(4000)
SET @xmlDoc='

<q:quakeml xmlns="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/bed/1.2" xmlns:catalog="http://anss.org/xmlns/catalog/0.1" xmlns:q="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/quakeml/1.2">
<eventParameters publicID="quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.quakeml">
<event catalog:datasource="nc" catalog:eventsource="nc" catalog:eventid="72431490" publicID="quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/nc72431490.quakeml"><description><type>earthquake name</type><text>7km W of Cobb, California</text></description><origin catalog:datasource="nc" catalog:dataid="nc72431490" catalog:eventsource="nc" catalog:eventid="72431490" publicID="quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/realtime/product/origin/nc72431490/nc/1429535409370/product.xml"><time><value>2015-04-20T13:08:32.490Z</value></time><longitude><value>-122.810997</value></longitude><latitude><value>38.8321648</value></latitude><depth><value>2340</value><uncertainty>940</uncertainty></depth><originUncertainty><horizontalUncertainty>380</horizontalUncertainty><preferredDescription>horizontal uncertainty</preferredDescription></originUncertainty><quality><usedPhaseCount>9</usedPhaseCount><usedStationCount>9</usedStationCount><standardError>0.02</standardError><azimuthalGap>114</azimuthalGap><minimumDistance>0.008787</minimumDistance></quality><evaluationMode>automatic</evaluationMode><creationInfo><agencyID>NC</agencyID><creationTime>2015-04-20T13:10:09.370Z</creationTime><version>0</version></creationInfo></origin><magnitude catalog:datasource="nc" catalog:dataid="nc72431490" catalog:eventsource="nc" catalog:eventid="72431490" publicID="quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/realtime/product/origin/nc72431490/nc/1429535409370/product.xml#magnitude"><mag><value>0.29</value></mag><type>md</type><stationCount>1</stationCount><originID>quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/realtime/product/origin/nc72431490/nc/1429535409370/product.xml</originID><evaluationMode>automatic</evaluationMode><creationInfo><agencyID>NC</agencyID><creationTime>2015-04-20T13:10:09.370Z</creationTime></creationInfo></magnitude><preferredOriginID>quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/realtime/product/origin/nc72431490/nc/1429535409370/product.xml</preferredOriginID><preferredMagnitudeID>quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/realtime/product/origin/nc72431490/nc/1429535409370/product.xml#magnitude</preferredMagnitudeID><type>earthquake</type><creationInfo><agencyID>nc</agencyID><creationTime>2015-04-20T13:17:04.229Z</creationTime><version>0</version></creationInfo></event>
<creationInfo><creationTime>2015-04-20T13:31:33.000Z</creationTime></creationInfo>
</eventParameters></q:quakeml>


'


declare @i int
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @i output, @xmlDoc,'<root xmlns:HaveToUsePlaceholderForDefaultAlias="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/bed/1.2" xmlns:q="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/quakeml/1.2" />'

SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@i, '/q:quakeml/HaveToUsePlaceholderForDefaultAlias:eventParameters/HaveToUsePlaceholderForDefaultAlias:event',2)
 WITH (
 MyDescriptionType       nvarchar(200)         'HaveToUsePlaceholderForDefaultAlias:description[1]/HaveToUsePlaceholderForDefaultAlias:type[1]/.'
,   MyMagValue   nvarchar(200)  'HaveToUsePlaceholderForDefaultAlias:magnitude[1]/HaveToUsePlaceholderForDefaultAlias:mag[1]/HaveToUsePlaceholderForDefaultAlias:value[1]/.'
,   MagType   nvarchar(200)  'HaveToUsePlaceholderForDefaultAlias:magnitude[1]/HaveToUsePlaceholderForDefaultAlias:type[1]/.'
  )

exec sp_xml_removedocument @i
```

You have to riddle your code with "HaveToUsePlaceholderForDefaultAlias:" all over the place.

I would suggest NOT using OPENXML.

Here is the "nodes" version.......with a much cleaner use of the default namespace.

```
declare @xmldoc xml

select @xmldoc =
'
<q:quakeml xmlns="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/bed/1.2" xmlns:catalog="http://anss.org/xmlns/catalog/0.1" xmlns:q="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/quakeml/1.2">
    <eventParameters publicID="quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.quakeml">
        <event catalog:datasource="nc" catalog:eventsource="nc" catalog:eventid="72431490" publicID="quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/nc72431490.quakeml">
            <description>
                <type>earthquake name</type>
                <text>7km W of Cobb, California</text>
            </description>
            <origin catalog:datasource="nc" catalog:dataid="nc72431490" catalog:eventsource="nc" catalog:eventid="72431490" publicID="quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/realtime/product/origin/nc72431490/nc/1429535409370/product.xml">
                <time>
                    <value>2015-04-20T13:08:32.490Z</value>
                </time>
                <longitude>
                    <value>-122.810997</value>
                </longitude>
                <latitude>
                    <value>38.8321648</value>
                </latitude>
                <depth>
                    <value>2340</value>
                    <uncertainty>940</uncertainty>
                </depth>
                <originUncertainty>
                    <horizontalUncertainty>380</horizontalUncertainty>
                    <preferredDescription>horizontal uncertainty</preferredDescription>
                </originUncertainty>
                <quality>
                    <usedPhaseCount>9</usedPhaseCount>
                    <usedStationCount>9</usedStationCount>
                    <standardError>0.02</standardError>
                    <azimuthalGap>114</azimuthalGap>
                    <minimumDistance>0.008787</minimumDistance>
                </quality>
                <evaluationMode>automatic</evaluationMode>
                <creationInfo>
                    <agencyID>NC</agencyID>
                    <creationTime>2015-04-20T13:10:09.370Z</creationTime>
                    <version>0</version>
                </creationInfo>
            </origin>
            <magnitude catalog:datasource="nc" catalog:dataid="nc72431490" catalog:eventsource="nc" catalog:eventid="72431490" publicID="quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/realtime/product/origin/nc72431490/nc/1429535409370/product.xml#magnitude">
                <mag>
                    <value>0.29</value>
                </mag>
                <type>md</type>
                <stationCount>1</stationCount>
                <originID>quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/realtime/product/origin/nc72431490/nc/1429535409370/product.xml</originID>
                <evaluationMode>automatic</evaluationMode>
                <creationInfo>
                    <agencyID>NC</agencyID>
                    <creationTime>2015-04-20T13:10:09.370Z</creationTime>
                </creationInfo>
            </magnitude>
            <preferredOriginID>quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/realtime/product/origin/nc72431490/nc/1429535409370/product.xml</preferredOriginID>
            <preferredMagnitudeID>quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/realtime/product/origin/nc72431490/nc/1429535409370/product.xml#magnitude</preferredMagnitudeID>
            <type>earthquake</type>
            <creationInfo>
                <agencyID>nc</agencyID>
                <creationTime>2015-04-20T13:17:04.229Z</creationTime>
                <version>0</version>
            </creationInfo>
        </event>
        <creationInfo>
            <creationTime>2015-04-20T13:31:33.000Z</creationTime>
        </creationInfo>
    </eventParameters>
</q:quakeml>

'



;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( 'http://quakeml.org/xmlns/quakeml/1.2' AS q, DEFAULT 'http://quakeml.org/xmlns/bed/1.2' )
SELECT 
    MyDescriptionType = Y.i.value('./description[1]/type[1]/.', 'varchar(64)')
,   MyMagValue = Y.i.value('./magnitude[1]/mag[1]/value[1]/.', 'varchar(64)')
,   MagType = Y.i.value('./magnitude[1]/type[1]/.', 'varchar(64)')


FROM 
    @xmldoc.nodes('/q:quakeml/eventParameters/event') AS Y(i)
```

APPEND:

You might want to put the info in a #temp table, THEN insert the data from the #temp table to the "real" table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Holder') IS NOT NULL
begin
    drop table #Holder
end


CREATE TABLE #Holder ( ID int identity (1000,1) , MyDescription varchar(64) , Longitude numeric(18,6) , Magnitude varchar(64) , MagType varchar(64) )


declare @xmldoc xml

select @xmldoc =
'
<q:quakeml xmlns="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/bed/1.2" xmlns:catalog="http://anss.org/xmlns/catalog/0.1" xmlns:q="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/quakeml/1.2">
    <eventParameters publicID="quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.quakeml">
        <event catalog:datasource="nc" catalog:eventsource="nc" catalog:eventid="72431490" publicID="quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/nc72431490.quakeml">
            <description>
                <type>earthquake name</type>
                <text>7km W of Cobb, California</text>
            </description>
            <origin catalog:datasource="nc" catalog:dataid="nc72431490" catalog:eventsource="nc" catalog:eventid="72431490" publicID="quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/realtime/product/origin/nc72431490/nc/1429535409370/product.xml">
                <time>
                    <value>2015-04-20T13:08:32.490Z</value>
                </time>
                <longitude>
                    <value>-122.810997</value>
                </longitude>
                <latitude>
                    <value>38.8321648</value>
                </latitude>
                <depth>
                    <value>2340</value>
                    <uncertainty>940</uncertainty>
                </depth>
                <originUncertainty>
                    <horizontalUncertainty>380</horizontalUncertainty>
                    <preferredDescription>horizontal uncertainty</preferredDescription>
                </originUncertainty>
                <quality>
                    <usedPhaseCount>9</usedPhaseCount>
                    <usedStationCount>9</usedStationCount>
                    <standardError>0.02</standardError>
                    <azimuthalGap>114</azimuthalGap>
                    <minimumDistance>0.008787</minimumDistance>
                </quality>
                <evaluationMode>automatic</evaluationMode>
                <creationInfo>
                    <agencyID>NC</agencyID>
                    <creationTime>2015-04-20T13:10:09.370Z</creationTime>
                    <version>0</version>
                </creationInfo>
            </origin>
            <magnitude catalog:datasource="nc" catalog:dataid="nc72431490" catalog:eventsource="nc" catalog:eventid="72431490" publicID="quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/realtime/product/origin/nc72431490/nc/1429535409370/product.xml#magnitude">
                <mag>
                    <value>0.29</value>
                </mag>
                <type>md</type>
                <stationCount>1</stationCount>
                <originID>quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/realtime/product/origin/nc72431490/nc/1429535409370/product.xml</originID>
                <evaluationMode>automatic</evaluationMode>
                <creationInfo>
                    <agencyID>NC</agencyID>
                    <creationTime>2015-04-20T13:10:09.370Z</creationTime>
                </creationInfo>
            </magnitude>
            <preferredOriginID>quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/realtime/product/origin/nc72431490/nc/1429535409370/product.xml</preferredOriginID>
            <preferredMagnitudeID>quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/realtime/product/origin/nc72431490/nc/1429535409370/product.xml#magnitude</preferredMagnitudeID>
            <type>earthquake</type>
            <creationInfo>
                <agencyID>nc</agencyID>
                <creationTime>2015-04-20T13:17:04.229Z</creationTime>
                <version>0</version>
            </creationInfo>
        </event>
        <creationInfo>
            <creationTime>2015-04-20T13:31:33.000Z</creationTime>
        </creationInfo>
    </eventParameters>
</q:quakeml>

'


;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( 'http://quakeml.org/xmlns/quakeml/1.2' AS q, DEFAULT 'http://quakeml.org/xmlns/bed/1.2' )

INSERT INTO #HOLDER (MyDescription  , Longitude  , Magnitude , MagType  ) 

SELECT 
    MyDescriptionType = Y.i.value('./description[1]/type[1]/.', 'varchar(64)')
,   MyLongitude = Y.i.value('./origin[1]/longitude[1]/.', 'numeric(18,6)')
,   MyMagValue = Y.i.value('./magnitude[1]/mag[1]/value[1]/.', 'varchar(64)')
,   MagType = Y.i.value('./magnitude[1]/type[1]/.', 'varchar(64)')


FROM 
    @xmldoc.nodes('/q:quakeml/eventParameters/event') AS Y(i)








/* Optional */   
/* CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_TempHolder_ID ON #Holder (ID) */
CREATE INDEX IDX_TempHolder_ID ON #Holder (ID)

/* HERE you go from #temp table to real table */
Insert into dbo.RealTable ( Description  , Longitude  , Magnitude , MagType  )
select MyDescription  , Longitude  , Magnitude , MagType  from #Holder







IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Holder') IS NOT NULL
begin
    drop table #Holder
end
```

Comment: i used node before but when i have to insert 1000 entry from an xml file it takes 15 minutes to load it in the database. Do you think there are other method ?

Comment: Instead of going straight from xml to the (real) table, create a #tempTable or a @ variableTable....populate that #tempTable or @ variableTable...and hten insert into the real table from there.  You want to separate the processing for the xml-shredding...from the INSERT.  I'm not saying this will work...its something to experiment with.  And experiment between a #tempTable and also a @ variableTable.

Comment: Still taking time but is much quicker thanks. now the problem is when i try very large xml file like 18megabyte in size i get web page unavailable(ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)

Comment: 18 MB file over asp.net...that is xml that you shred.....?  Youch.  You'll have to modify your webpage timeout times significantly.

Comment: That's a totally different question.........not germane to this one.  I'd suggest you start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

For raw text of loaded document in WordProcessingDocument, you can use.

```
string rawText = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.ChildElements[0].InnerText;
```

For XML:

```
string rawText = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.ChildElements[0].InnerXml;
```